# Notepad++ : Replace all the words starting with *

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace all the words starting with *

for eg:-

```
*finish :- finish (* removed)
a*finish :- a*finish (not removed)
```

What regular expression would work in notepad++ ?

I tried `^*` but it says invalid regular expression.

similarly for `^[\\*]` doesn't work as well.

For normar characters it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. Fill in *Find what*: `(^|\s)\*(.+?)(\s|$)`
3. Fill in *Replace with*: `\1\2\3`

[**[ Regex Demo ]**](https://regex101.com/r/GvFGKX/4)

Explanation:

```
(^|\s)    => Group 1: start of line -^- or any white-space character -\s-
\*        => * character
(.+?)     => Group 2: one or many characters on lowest length until next match
(\s|$)    => Group 3: any white-space character -\s- or end of line -$-
```

Comment: Group 2 and 3 are superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `^(\s+)?\*.+`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/eKdgDu/2)

Answer (score 2):

Replace each match of this regex:

```
(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))\*
```

with a blank string.

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GvFGKX/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\s)` - positive lookbehind to make sure that the current position is preceded by a whitespace
- `|` - OR
- `(?<=^)` - positive lookbehind to make sure that the current position is preceded by start of the line
- `\*` - If any of the above conditions satisfy, match the `*`